# Jquery UI jConfirm dialog not showing up on gridComplete of jqgrid

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using `jConfirm` dialog for confirmation in `jqgrid`. All i want is when the `gridComplete` triggers it should popup a `jConfirm` dialog with Ok and cancel buttons when i hit ok it should `setSeletion` of Rows in `jqgrid`. My code is as follows:

```
// My ajax call in gridComplete function in jqgrid
function listSelectedUsers(data) {
$.ajax({
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: urlPath,
            data: { countryID: countryID},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                  jConfirm(data, 'JqGrid Popup', function(confirmation) {
                   if (confirmation) {

                   }
               });
            },
            error: function(data) {

            }
        });
}

//jqgrid code
// on gridComplete function call, does not show up jConfirm dialog popup.
gridComplete: function() {
    listSelectedUsers(data);
},
```

Please suggest me the solution ASAP.
Thanks in advance.